# How to compare tables one column value with other column having a group of values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Preq: Both columns 'name' and 'sname' from below tables are of type varchar and id is int

**Table1**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1.txt |
| 2 | test2.txt |

**Table2**

| id | sname |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | ['test1'] |
| 222 | ['test1', 'test2'] |

**Requirement:** To get the matching values of column 'name' and column 'sname' from table1 & table2 respectively

**MySQL query:**

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
        ON CONCAT('[\'', substring_index(name,'.',1), '\']') LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.scname, '%');
```

****NOTE:****

`[\'', substring_index(name,'.',1), '\']`: This format is to compare table1.name with table2.sname values hence pop '.txt' char and add [ ] to table1.name value

**Current (wrong) Output**

| id | name | id | sname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1.txt | 11 | ['test1'] |

**Expected Output** (Expecting below 2 rows to be returned, since in table2, 2nd row also has a matching varchar 'test1')

| id | name | id | sname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1.txt | 11 | ['test1'] |
| 2 | test1.txt | 22 | ['test1', 'test2'] |

How to get this result?

Comment: Precise values are not clear. Show your tables and sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: Does sname column contain `'` or `"`? And why aren't there three rows (test1 is present in both rows of table2)

Comment: sname column contain '

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: … See the [help] for more on [how to ask good questions](/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics. See also the [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "*table1.name*" to match "*table2.sname*" as a substring, you need to change the condition to `table2.sname LIKE CONCAT('%\'', substring_index(name,'.',1), '\'%')`.

Then if you want to take the smallest "*table2.sname*" string for each "*id*" you can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`, and get always the first value for each "*table1.id*" (`WHERE rn = 1`).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT table1.id    AS t1_id,
           table1.name  AS t1_name,
           table2.id    AS t2_id,
           table2.sname AS t2_name, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY table1.id ORDER BY LENGTH(table2.sname)) AS rn
    FROM table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 
            ON table2.sname LIKE CONCAT('%\'', substring_index(name,'.',1), '\'%')
)
SELECT t1_id,
       t1_name,
       t2_id,
       t2_name
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pktQBgiZXiye3WLzqaFQEJ/0).